# lubridate month vector generation with NA on 31.08.2022

Tags: r, format, lubridate

How can I avoid that this statement gets NA for september when run on the 31.08.2022?

```
format(lubridate::as_date(as.character(lubridate::now() + months(-1:2))), "%m.%Y")
[1] "07.2022" "08.2022" NA        "10.2022"
```

Comment: Unless your data is character strings you don't need `as_date(as.character(.))`.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Add and subtract months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/mplus.html)

```
format(lubridate::as_date(as.character(lubridate::now() %m+% months(-1:2))), "%m.%Y")
[1] "07.2022" "08.2022" "09.2022" "10.2022"
```

Comment: Unless the data is character strings there's no need for `as_date(as.character(.))`, a simpler `format(now(tzone = "UTC") %m+% months(-1:2), "%m.%Y")` is enough. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dmonths` instead of `months`, I also removed some redundant code.
This will do:

```
format(now() + dmonths(-1:2), "%m.%Y")
# [1] "07.2022" "08.2022" "09.2022" "10.2022"
```